# Android Multiline notifications using the PARSE platform

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications

I am trying to get multiline notifications to show up in the Android notification menu. Right now when I send a push it will scroll at the top and then within the Notification bar it is only one line. I use PARSE as my push notification provider. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: How do you show your notifications now?

Comment: I have same issue any solution? I am sending notification from Parse, not from code.

Answer (score 0):

Intercept PARSE notification in Android App by extending one class by BroadcastReceiver(modify your AndroidMenifest.xml accordingly) & get the DATA required. Then generate your own customize notifications. & you will generate Multiple Notifications as per requirement.